# Union of two network diagrams

Tags: algorithm, nodes, graph-theory, topology

Can anyone point me to the right data structures / algorithms to accomplish the following?

I would like to combine (Union?) the following two sets of nodes to get the third set.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short answer

1. Union the node sets.
2. Union the edge sets.

## Long answer

I'll assume you're using a graph data structure in which there are `Node` instances, where each `Node` has a `string Name` and a `list<Node> Next`.

Let's call your two graphs `G` and `H`, where a graph is a `list<Node>`.

Let `GNames` and `HNames` be the sets of node names in each of the graphs. Let `MNames` be the union of `GNames` and `HNames`.

Create a new graph `list<Node> M` where there is a new `Node` for each name in `MNames`.

Build `map<string, Node> GLookup, HLookup, MLookup` as mappings from node name to `Node` for each of the `list<Node> G, H, M`.

For each `Node u` in this new graph `M`, compute `NextNames` as the union of `GLookup[u.Name].Next.Select(v => v.Name)` and  `HLookup[u.Name].Next.Select(v => v.Name)`, then for each name `name` in `NextNames`, add `MLookup[name]` to `u.Next`.

`M` is now your merged graph.

## Pseudocode

```
list<Node> merge(list<Node> G, list<Node> H)
    GNames = G.Select(u => u.Name)
    HNames = H.Select(u => u.Name)
    MNames = union(GNames, HNames)
    M = MNames.Select(name => new Node(name))
    GLookup = G.ToMap(u => u.Name)
    HLookup = H.ToMap(u => u.Name)
    MLookup = M.ToMap(u => u.Name)
    foreach u in M
        NextNames = union(
                        GLookup[u.Name].Next.Select(v => v.Name),
                        HLookup[u.Name].Next.Select(v => v.Name))
        foreach name in NextNames
            u.Next.Add(MLookup[name])
    return M
```

Comment: This is definitely correct, but that's more of a mathematical operation than a data structure operation. Actually implementing this requires some work depending on how the graph is represented.

Comment: @templatetypedef I expanded for the case of a node-class-based graph representation.

Comment: Thanks... at first I didn't like the brevity of the short answer... but then I thought about it for 30 seconds and got it! :)

Comment: @BrianRice Right, conceptually it's a *very* simple operation. Turning it into code that works is easy as long as you're careful about creating completely new `Node` objects. Don't try to reuse the existing ones.

Answer (score 4):

Typically graphs can be represented as either adjacency matrices or adjacency lists. Either way to union them isn't hard.

From the adjacency list perspective, you have

```
list1 = [[A,[B,K]],[B,[C,D,E]],...]
list2 = [[A,[B]],[B,[C,D,E]],...]
```

so all you would have to do is union the sublist per node in your adjacency lists

```
list3 = [[A,UNION([B,K],[B])]...]
```

For the adjacency matrix, it is trivial. Simply loop through each aij in the matrix, and if it is 0 and the corresponding entry in the other matrix is 1, set it to 1.

If graph 1 had something like:

```
    A   B   C
A   1   1   0
B   0   1   0
C   0   1   1
```

and graph 2 had something like:

```
    A   B   C
A   1   1   0
B   0   1   1
C   0   0   1
```

then graph 3 would end up with

```
    A   B   C
A   1   1   0
B   0   1   1
C   0   1   1
```